# why does pointer get its previous value returning from a function

Tags: c++, pointers

guys how does the ptr get its previous value? code is simple, I just wondered why it doesn't store the address value that it's been assigned within the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void test(int*);
int main( )
{
    int temp;
    int*ptr;   
    temp=3;
    ptr = &temp;
    test(ptr);


    printf("\nvalue of the pointed memory after exiting from the function:%d\n",*ptr);
    printf("\nvalue of the pointer after exiting from the function:%d\n",ptr);


system("pause ");
return 0;
} 


void test(int *tes){

    int temp2;        
    temp2=710;
    tes =&temp2;

    printf("\nvalue of the pointed memory inside the function%d\n",*tes);
    printf("\nvalue of the pointer inside the function%d\n",tes);


}
```

output is:

value of the pointed memory inside the function:**710**

value of the pointer inside the function:**3405940**

value of the pointed memory after exiting from the function:**3**

value of the pointer after exiting from the function:**3406180**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You passed the pointer by value.

The pointer inside `test` is a *copy* of the pointer inside `main`. Any changes made to the copy do not affect the original.

This is potentially confusing because, by using an `int*`, you're passing a handle ("reference", though actually a reference is a separate thing that exists in C++) to an `int` and thus avoiding copies of that `int`. However, the pointer itself is an object in its own right, and you're passing *that* around by value.

(You're also attempting to point your pointer to an `int` that's local to the function `test`. Using it will be invalid.)

Comment: +1 for the answer. But didn't understand why the pointer will be invalid if it is pointing to local variable of the function. In the snippet OP is not the returning the pointer.

Comment: @Mahesh: It won't be, but if he'd handled the pointer correctly, then he'd have this ancillary problem. :) "it" is the new value of the pointer. That sentence wasn't entirely clear; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is passed into the function by value, in other words a copy is made of it. In the function you change the copy, but that does not alter the value in main. If you wanted to change that, you would need to use a pointer to  a pointer.

Comment: you are using call by reference (i.e. via a pointer) with regard to the `int` value, but not with regard to the pointer itself.

Comment: @user675844: Yea, for the `int` (pass "by pointer"; "by reference" is actually something different, but I know what you meant). But not for the pointer itself. :)

Answer (score 1):

In case the other answers describing the issue are not sufficient.
The code you want so you can change the value is along these lines

```
test(&ptr);

void test(int **tes){
    int *temp2 = new int;
    *tes =&temp2;
}
```

Alternativly, don't mess with raw pointers.  `shared_ptr<>` and `&` can be your friend!